# Why does my ASP.NET App show an extra table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, repository

This is a hybrid (MVC and Web forms) Web app to rate doctors.  Here is my code for the ratings Web form.  Why is there an extra table with the first record under the GridView?  It happened after I pressed "Select" in the first row, but why does it stay there after I stop and run it again?  It's not a cache problem, because it shows in different browsers.  Thanks in advance!

[image]

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Rating.aspx.cs" Inherits="MidtermApplication.Rating" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSourceDoctor" runat="server" DeleteMethod="Remove" InsertMethod="Add" SelectMethod="GetDoctor" TypeName="MidtermApplication.Models.TestApplicationDoctorRepo" UpdateMethod="Update" DataObjectTypeName="MidtermApplication.Models.Doctor">
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridViewDoctor" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSourceDoctor" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridViewDoctor_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <Columns>
            <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="DoctorPicture" HeaderText="DoctorPicture">
            </asp:ImageField>            
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DoctorName" HeaderText="DoctorName" SortExpression="DoctorName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DoctorSpecialty" HeaderText="DoctorSpecialty" SortExpression="DoctorSpecialty" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rate Now">
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" GroupName="RateNow" Text="1"></asp:RadioButton>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" GroupName="RateNow" Text="2"></asp:RadioButton>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton3" runat="server" GroupName="RateNow" Text="3"></asp:RadioButton>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton4" runat="server" GroupName="RateNow" Text="4"></asp:RadioButton>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton5" runat="server" GroupName="RateNow" Text="5"></asp:RadioButton>

            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:ButtonField AccessibleHeaderText="Save Rating" HeaderText="Save Rating" Text="Save" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="fave" HeaderText="Favorite" SortExpression="fave" InsertVisible="False" Visible="True" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

</asp:Content>
```

Code behind:

```
namespace MidtermApplication
{
    public partial class Rating : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        TestApplicationDoctorRepo repo;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TestApplicationDoctorRepo.InitApp(this);

        }

        protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void GridViewDoctor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is there an extra table with the first record under the GridView?

it is a **details view**, you can remove it in design mode in visual studio.

**Update:**

[image]

Solution:

You must create a new page, and design this page again.

Comment: I don't have a Details view any more.  I deleted it.

Comment: I added a screen shot to the bottom of my question.

Comment: I did that, and ran in a different browser, but it's still there.

Comment: It's just Master.Master.cs: 
namespace MidtermApplication
{
    public partial class Master : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}

Comment: I run it, works fine. select button and details view not exist. see image in my answer.

Comment: Interesting. In FF, IE, Chrome, and Opera I get the Details view.

Comment: Best solution: create this page again, (copy aspx to new page)